# Google Analytics Mobile doesn't count

Tags: android, google-analytics

Got a strange thing going on, I recently started counting visitors of my app, it was working fine. Ater a while I saw that on Google Analytics, you can point out if it is a website or mobile. I made a new profile with 'mobile' selected, replaced the code in my app, but since then, it isn't counting anymore.. I waited more then 24 hours.

I use

```
mGATracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
            mGATracker.startNewSession("UA-xxxxxxxx-x", this);
            mGATracker.trackPageView("/About");
```

And dispatch in the onDestroy method:
@Override

```
public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            super.onDestroy();
            mGATracker.dispatch();
            mGATracker.stopSession();
        } catch (Exception error) {
            Log.e("<YOUR_TAG>", "onDestroy: " + error.toString());
        }
    }
```

Anybody else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA ver 1 requires 'website' type of panel.